# What indicates instructors' experience in online technology?

Tags: research-process, thesis, masters, online-learning, technology

My research is qualitative; it aims to explore the experience of EFL instructors about online teaching. What potential semi-structured interview questions about experience towards online technology can I make to gather data that will achieve the research aims?

I am particularly seeking experience indicators in this post; in other words, how to ask experience-grasping questions to participants is what I am trying to do.

Thank you.

Comment: This is off topic as it is about the content of your research. It is a question for your advisor. See the help center: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help